# string join object.values where object.key equals condition

Tags: javascript, string, object, attributes

I have an object that i need to join into a sql condition string.
This is the object:

```
   qFilters= {EMPRESA: "EMPRESA='DEMO'", QTD: "QTD IS NOT NULL ", " ": "OR MONTANTE IS NOT NULL"}
```

This is the string result:

```
whereStr += Object.values(qFilters).join(" AND ");
```

The problem is i need to join only the ones that have atribute name. The last atribute dont have a name so i dont need the "AND".

If teh propertie dont have a name skip  "AND" and use only the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a clear question: `If teh propertie dont have a name skip "AND" and use only the value.` What is the expected output from the above example?

Comment: "EMPRESA='DEMO' AND QTD IS NOT NULL  OR MONTANTE IS NOT NULL"-----skip the "and" on last atribute of filters object, because no atribute name.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way to do it, but really, you should probably re-think this whole design. There are surely better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```js
var whereObj = {EMPRESA: "EMPRESA='DEMO'", QTD: "QTD IS NOT NULL ", " ": "OR MONTANTE IS NOT NULL"};

var where = "";
var first_loop = true;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(whereObj)) {
  if(key.trim()){
    if(!first_loop) where += " AND";
    where += " " + value;
  }else{
    where += " " + value;
  }
  first_loop = false;
}

console.log(where);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` in order to filter on the key type:

```js
const qFilters= {EMPRESA: "EMPRESA='DEMO'", QTD: "QTD IS NOT NULL ", " ": "OR MONTANTE IS NOT NULL"}

const res = Object.keys(qFilters).reduce((query, key) => {
  if(!!key.trim()){
    return [query, qFilters[key]].join(' AND ');
  } else {
    return [query, qFilters[key]].join(' ');
  }
});

console.log(res)
```